# Pass the name and value to JavaScript onClick function?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, coldfusion-9

I have function that originally should disable group of check boxes if they are not checked. This function was designed to work onClick() and I was passing one argument onClick(this) from check box element. Now I need this function to be triggered on page load and I would need to pass the value from database. Tricky part is that I have more than one group of check boxes. Here is example of my HTML layout:

```
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="o_outcomeCk" id="o_firstOutcome" value="1" tabIndex="1" <cfif Trim(myData.o_outcomeCk) EQ 1>checked</cfif> onClick="ckChange('o_outcomeCk', 1)">First Outcome
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="o_outcomeCk" id="o_secondOutcome" value="2" tabIndex="1" <cfif Trim(myData.o_outcomeCk) EQ 2>checked</cfif> onClick="ckChange('o_outcomeCk', 2)">Second Outcome
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="o_progressCk" id="o_firstProgress" value="1" tabIndex="1" <cfif Trim(myData.o_progressCk) EQ 1>checked</cfif> onClick="ckChange('o_progressCk', 1)">First Progress
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="o_progressCk" id="o_secondProgress" value="2" tabIndex="1" <cfif Trim(myData.o_progressCk) EQ 2>checked</cfif> onClick="ckChange('o_progressCk', 2)">Second Progress
    </td>
</tr>
```

Above in each onClick function I have tried to pass the checkbox name and value. When user click on the check box I should disable one that is unchecked. Also when I load the page value from database will decide which check box is checked and one that is not check should be disabled at this time as well. Here is my Javascript function:

```
function ckChange(ckType, ckVal){
    var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType);
    var numChecked = 0;
    var index = 0;

    for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){
        if(ckName[i].checked){
            numChecked++;
            index = i;
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){
        if(numChecked == 0){
            ckName[i].disabled = false;
        }else{
            if(i != index){
                ckName[i].disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason my function doesn't work as expected. I'm thinking also of passing the id each time I call this fucntion on click but then how that will work on page load? Here is what I do to call the function when user gets to the page:

```
<cfoutput>
    ckChange('o_outcomeCk','#Trim(myData.o_outcomeCk)#');
    ckChange('o_progressCk','#Trim(myData.o_progressCk)#');
</cfoutput>
```

Here I'm able to pass the name and value from database. I'm open for suggestions and different approach if that would be more efficient. My current code doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: So what you're saying is, for each pair of checkboxes, if one or both of the boxes isn't checked, it should be disabled on page load?

Comment: If one of the check boxes in the group is checked, rest of them should be disabled. If there is no checked check boxes in the group then all of them should be enabled.

Comment: Are the checkboxes supposed to be marked checked at page load, if the database value determines it should be checked?  Otherwise, the initial check will always enable all the boxes.

Comment: Yes they should be, I have cfif statements that will check the value for each checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution. I had to remove your ColdFusion code, since the code editor doesn't support it, and I inserted some temporary JavaScript (the first four statements) to simulate some imported data.

If one of the check boxes is checked, the other will be disabled. If neither is checked, they will both be enabled. This solution should be scalable as well, if you add more check boxes to either group.

Try the example to make sure it does what you need it to. It's simulating the first box in `o_outcomeCk` and the second box in `o_progressCk` as being checked.

```js
// simulate imported data & CF checkbox selecting
document.getElementsByName("o_outcomeCk")[0].checked = true;
document.getElementsByName("o_progressCk")[1].checked = true;
ckChange('o_outcomeCk',1);
ckChange('o_progressCk',2);


function ckChange(ckType, ckVal){
  var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType);
  var numChecked = 0;   // counter
  var index = 0;        // which index is checked
  for(var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++){
    // check which boxes in this set are checked
    if (ckName[i].checked) {
      // if the box that was clicked is checked
      numChecked++;
      index = i;
    }
  }
  if (numChecked == 0) {
    // enable both boxes
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      ckName[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
  else {
    // disable other box
    for (var i = 0; i < ckName.length; i++) {
      if (i != index) {
        ckName[i].disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="o_outcomeCk" id="o_firstOutcome" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange('o_outcomeCk', 1)">First Outcome
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="o_outcomeCk" id="o_secondOutcome" value="2" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange('o_outcomeCk', 2)">Second Outcome
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="o_progressCk" id="o_firstProgress" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange('o_progressCk', 1)">First Progress
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="o_progressCk" id="o_secondProgress" value="2" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange('o_progressCk', 2)">Second Progress
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** Below is an alternate version of the JavaScript, which uses only one `for` loop.  If you want to use it, just swap it out for the JavaScript code above.  The only HTML that needs to be changed is the `onclick` attribute for each checkbox, which should be changed to `onClick="ckChange(this)"`.

```js
// simulate imported data & CF checkbox selecting
document.getElementsByName("o_progressCk")[1].checked = true;
ckChange("o_outcomeCk", 0);
ckChange("o_progressCk", 2);

function ckChange(that, val){
    var isChecked = false;
    var wasClicked = false;
    var index = 0;
    var ckType = that;
    if (!!that.type) {    // if called from a click
      ckType = that.name;
      wasClicked = true;
      if (!!that.checked) {
        index = that.value - 1;
        isChecked = true;
      }  
    }

    var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType);

    for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){
        if (isChecked) {
          // if called from click and box was checked
          if (index != i) {
            ckName[i].disabled = true;
          }
        }
        else if (wasClicked) {
          // if called from click and box was unchecked
          ckName[i].disabled = false;
        }
        else {
          // if on load
          if (val != 0) {
            // one is checked
            if (i != val - 1) {
              ckName[i].disabled = true;
            }
          }
          else {
            // none checked
            ckName[i].disabled = false;
          }          
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help on this. My problem was that I only had one loop. I still think that might be doable with one loop but your solution works. I updated my question and removed one extra loop from your answer.

Comment: Nice improvement. My code was kinda clunky. I think it could be done with one loop, too. If I have time today I'll try it.

Comment: @espresso_coffee Are you gonna be sticking with just 2 check boxes per set, or is there a chance there will be more down the road? The reason I ask is that one loop would be a lot easier to accomplish if you knew there would only be two boxes per set.

Comment: I'm trying to make this function dynamic, so I can have multiple elements in each set of check boxes. So answer is I can have more than 2 in the set, and each set can have different number of elements.

Comment: @espresso_coffee Are you trying to get it down to 1 loop for efficiency or for code simplicity?  Meaning, if you had multiple loops but only 1 was executed (which loop depended on what occurred) would that fit what you're going for?

Comment: Just efficiency and code simplicity. Also Looks to me that this solution doesn't use the value that I have passed in the function. Should I get rid of that argument or we should keep it?

Comment: @espresso_coffee Yeah, you can remove it. I can get the function down to one loop when called on click, but when called on load it's a lot harder to only loop through once.

Comment: I had the same problem and that's why I passed in the value that way I can combine with the name of the element.

Comment: @espresso_coffee If neither box is checked on load, does the ColdFusion initial function call pass in `0` for the value?

Comment: @espresso_coffee Assuming a `0` gets passed in if no boxes are selected for a particular set, I updated my answer to provide a version of the code that uses only one `for` loop.  (See the section of my answer toward the bottom, labeled **Update**.)